# Which chrome extension should I use for making music online?

Tags: music

I live with my 3 year old baby girl. Due to the ongoing covid-19 outbreak, she is unable to go out and play with her friends. She loves music. I was wondering if there is a chrome extension for making music online. I am a fan of garage band on ios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into Soundtrap. You can record, do vocals, and apply loops. It is a great collaborative music creation tool.